# External Structs and Multiple Headers

Tags: c, struct, extern

I have a confusion about external structs. I have to define a global instance of the struct in a file other than which the struct is defined (as a RAM variable which I do not know what it is exactly).

Below is an example that GCC can compile and it runs correct while Code Composer Studio gives compile-time errors.

I want to learn where the problem is, how GCC can compile, and where/how I should use the extern declaration.

Any comment would be appreciated.

***person.h***

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
struct person {
    int age;
};
typedef struct person PERSON;
void modifyPerson();
#endif // PERSON_H
```

***personRam.h***

```
#ifndef PERSONRAM_H
#define PERSONRAM_H
#include "person.h"
PERSON p1;
#endif // PERSONRAM_H
```

***modifyPerson.c***

```
#include "person.h"
#include "personRam.h"
void modifyPerson() {
    p1.age = 10;
}
```

***main.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "person.h"
#include "personRam.h"
int main() {
    modifyPerson();
    printf("%d", p1.age);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In order to have external structure, you must use keyword `extern` at least once. You didn't. So where is the external structure? Nowhere. You have duplicate instances of that structure. GCC is being way too forgiving for your mistakes.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/decl/decldef.html

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko Where are the duplicates? I declared it once in personRam.h. Am I wrong?

Comment: @groove: Wrong. You both declare and define. Then include this file in multiple places.

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko: I think I get it. Each _personRam.h_ inclusion creates a duplicate since the declaration in _personRam.h_ is not `extern`. Now for the RAM (global) variables, I have _personRam.h_ and _personRam.c_. I **first** declare it in _personRam.c_, and explicitly (`extern`) declare it in _personRam.h_ and include _personRam.h_ where I need to use the variable. [In my project these globals will be stored in the ram of the DSP, and in order to do this I will use some compiler directives]. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should not get a compiler error, but a linker error, saying that `p1` is defined multiple times. At least that's what I guess is the problem.

The reason is that you *define* the variable in a header file, which you then include in multiple source files. This means that the definition is in both source files (The preprocessor `#include` directive literally puts the contents of the header file in place of the include "statement").

If you *declare* the variable as `extern` in the header file, and *define* it in one source file it should work.

So in `personRam.h`

```
extern PERSON p1;
```

And in one of the source files:

```
PERSON p1;
```

Comment: What I need is defining `p1` in _personRam.h_. May I do it?

So instead of including _personRam.h_ in all files which I need `p1`, I should `extern PERSON p1` in those files. Am I wrong?

By the way, your correction about the compiler-linker error is wright.

Comment: @groove Yes that would work, but I would rather create a source file `personRam.c` for the definition and have the `extern` declaration in the header file, and include the header file in all files that needs that variable.

Comment: Now my _main.c_ and _modifyPerson.c_ do not include _personRam.h_ but they include _globals.h_ which has just `extern PERSON p1;`. If I declare `PERSON p1;` in _personRam.h_ it gives error; but instead I added _personRam.c_ which has `#include "personRam.h"` and `PERSON p1;`. This compiles, but still I feel I am doing something wrong (so I am acting this dumb).

Comment: Instead of using another header (_globals.h_), I declare in _personRam.c_ and `extern` it in _personRam.h_. I'll include _personRam.h_ where I need that variable.

Answer (score 1):

On which operating system are you compiling, and for which target system?

For what it is worth, Linux (& Unix-es) and Windows have different linking semantics.
Read [Levine's "Linkers & Loaders"](http://www.iecc.com/linker/) book for details.

Comment: I'm on MS Windows targeting Windows with GCC and a DSP with CCS.